# Bash return value of test -e $file always returns false

Tags: bash, operators

I would like to check if a path is valid in Bash. However the lower code always returns false, even if the path is valid.

```
# Test if path is valid
mytest=$(test -e $myPath && test -f $myPath)

if [[ ! $mytest ]]; then 
        echo 'Path invalid. Stop..'
        exit 
fi
```

How can I improve the code?

Comment: Only `if [[ ! -d "$myPath" ]]; then`?

Comment: `if ! [[ -e $mypath && -f $mypath ]]; then ...; fi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$()` command substitution captures the **output** of a command, not the **exit status**.

- $mytest will be empty
- `[[ ... ]]` with only one operand (not counting `!`) returns "true" if the operand *is not empty*. Because $mytest *is* empty, the test result is "false negated"

To fix it:

1. following your style:

   ```bash
   test -e "$myPath" && test -f "$myPath"   # quote your variables
   mytest=$?                                # capture the exit status immediately

   if [[ $mytest -ne 0 ]]; then 
       echo 'Path invalid. Stop..'
       exit 
   fi
   ```
2. more idiomatic bash:

   ```bash
   if [[ ! (-e $myPath && -f $myPath) ]]; then 
       echo 'Path invalid. Stop..' >&2
       exit 
   fi
   ```

Comment: `-f` implies `-e`, so you could just write `if ! [[ -f $myPath ]]`. (I like the `!` to negate the exit status rather than the condition, but that's surely a matter of opinion.)